# Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

I want that the bot gives the reacter a role. But it doesnt work. Does anyone know where the problem is? Im coding in discord.js v12

```
if (user.bot) return;

if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

if (user.bot) return;
if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
if (reaction.message.guild.id !== "753289194738024632") return;

if (reaction.message.channel.id === "753290581412937832") {
    const cs = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "csgo");
    const vl = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "valorant");
    const fn = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "fortnite");

    let role = reaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '753290549548679229');
    member.roles.add(role.id);
```

Comment: Make sure `member` is member of the `GuildMember` property and not `User` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it to this:

```
if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return message.reply('This command does not work in DMs') //checks if the command wasnt executed in DMs
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '753290549548679229');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `reaction` to `message`

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '753290549548679229');
```

I think `reaction.guild` isn't a valid function

Comment: Not its still not working. The console give me this error: "ReferenceError: message is not defined"

Comment: You did not defined message, are you using a command handler, or `client.on('message')...`?

Comment: Make sure you're passing `message` in the message event

Comment: Then this error is here: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined

Comment: Use `reaction.message.guild`

Comment: Yes, try what @Lioness100 said

Comment: And now this is the error: "ReferenceError: member is not defined"

Comment: Yes, you did not defined member

Comment: Sure I did. But now I have the error by the role.. TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: I don't know if the id you provided is just an example, but you can use the id in `member.roles.add`, if it is a reaction-role command, you can try seeing [Collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html), I think it will be helpful

Comment: No the ID is not an example :)

Comment: Oh, but the try the link I put in my comment, I think it will help you